# SQL and Codeigniter Calculating Compound Interest With Regular Payments

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

favorite
So I am currently building a system where the user inputs 'interest', 'monthly_deposit' and 'start_date'.

I then want to query the current value of 'FV'.

I need some help writing the query.

I was trying this out, but im getting lost. I think im very wrong, I just need some guidance here

```
SELECT ((I/C + 1) AND (N*C) + R) * EXP(SUM(COALESCE(LOG)(1)/(I/C)
```

[image]

**My values**

P = 0 (always)

I = 'interest'

C = 12 (always)

N = 'start_date'

R = 'monthly_deposit'

Comment: not sure it helps http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488147/write-a-differential-equation-for-compound-interest

Comment: Thanks, il check it out 

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT (P*(POWER((1+(i DIV c)),(n * c)))) + ((R * (POWER((1+(i DIV c)),(n * c)) - 1)) DIV (i DIV c)) as fav
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try soon